# Debian 7 black screen after loading OS

Tags: debian

I have laptop Sony Vaio VPCCA with Debian Wheezy(7.1) installed as second OS. It worked fine for few weeks but now if I try to start Debian, there is all the loading stuff and when the GUI should start, the screen just goes black. Somebody has recomended me to check the `/var/log/X*log` file in recovery mode but I didn't find anything bad in it. Here's the `/var/log/X*log`

```
[    34.965] 
X.Org X Server 1.12.4
Release Date: 2012-08-27
[    34.965] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[    34.965] Build Operating System: Linux 3.10-3-amd64 x86_64 Debian
[    34.965] Current Operating System: Linux debian-vaico 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.51-1 x86_64
[    34.965] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-4-amd64 root=UUID=a5652e6e-7a3f-4b9e-a33e-b2000ae46c1e ro quiet
[    34.965] Build Date: 21 October 2013  04:49:48PM
[    34.965] xorg-server 2:1.12.4-6+deb7u1 (Moritz Muehlenhoff <jmm@debian.org>) 
[    34.965] Current version of pixman: 0.26.0
[    34.965]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[    34.965] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[    34.965] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Sun Dec 15 09:28:41 2013
[    35.100] (==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
[    35.100] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[    35.273] (==) ServerLayout "aticonfig Layout"
[    35.273] (**) |-->Screen "aticonfig-Screen[0]-0" (0)
[    35.273] (**) |   |-->Monitor "aticonfig-Monitor[0]-0"
[    35.274] (**) |   |-->Device "aticonfig-Device[0]-0"
[    35.274] (==) Automatically adding devices
[    35.274] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[    35.458] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[    35.458]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    35.483] (WW) The directory "/var/lib/defoma/x-ttcidfont-conf.d/dirs/TrueType" does not exist.
[    35.483]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    35.483] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi,
    built-ins
[    35.483] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[    35.483] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[    35.483] (II) Loader magic: 0x7fc315dfeae0
[    35.483] (II) Module ABI versions:
[    35.483]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[    35.483]    X.Org Video Driver: 12.1
[    35.483]    X.Org XInput driver : 16.0
[    35.483]    X.Org Server Extension : 6.0
[    35.485] (--) PCI:*(0:1:0:0) 1002:6760:104d:9081 rev 0, Mem @ 0xe0000000/268435456, 0xf7e20000/131072, I/O @ 0x0000d000/256, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[    35.485] (II) Open ACPI successful (/var/run/acpid.socket)
[    35.485] (II) "extmod" will be loaded by default.
[    35.485] (II) "dbe" will be loaded by default.
[    35.485] (II) "glx" will be loaded by default.
[    35.485] (II) "record" will be loaded by default.
[    35.485] (II) "dri" will be loaded by default.
[    35.485] (II) "dri2" will be loaded by default.
[    35.485] (II) LoadModule: "extmod"
[    35.690] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libextmod.so
[    35.729] (II) Module extmod: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    35.729]    compiled for 1.12.4, module version = 1.0.0
[    35.729]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[    35.729]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[    35.729] (II) Loading extension SELinux
[    35.729] (II) Loading extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
[    35.729] (II) Loading extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
[    35.729] (II) Loading extension XFree86-DGA
[    35.730] (II) Loading extension DPMS
[    35.730] (II) Loading extension XVideo
[    35.730] (II) Loading extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
[    35.730] (II) Loading extension X-Resource
[    35.730] (II) LoadModule: "dbe"
[    35.730] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdbe.so
[    35.752] (II) Module dbe: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    35.752]    compiled for 1.12.4, module version = 1.0.0
[    35.752]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[    35.752]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[    35.752] (II) Loading extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
[    35.752] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[    35.752] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[    36.010] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    36.010]    compiled for 1.12.4, module version = 1.0.0
[    36.010]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[    36.010] (==) AIGLX enabled
[    36.013] (II) Loading extension GLX
[    36.013] (II) LoadModule: "record"
[    36.014] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/librecord.so
[    36.031] (II) Module record: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    36.031]    compiled for 1.12.4, module version = 1.13.0
[    36.031]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[    36.031]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[    36.031] (II) Loading extension RECORD
[    36.031] (II) LoadModule: "dri"
[    36.031] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdri.so
[    36.063] (II) Module dri: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    36.063]    compiled for 1.12.4, module version = 1.0.0
[    36.063]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[    36.063] (II) Loading extension XFree86-DRI
[    36.063] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[    36.063] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdri2.so
[    36.064] (II) Module dri2: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    36.064]    compiled for 1.12.4, module version = 1.2.0
[    36.064]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[    36.064] (II) Loading extension DRI2
[    36.064] (II) LoadModule: "fglrx"
[    36.064] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fglrx_drv.so
[    36.374] (II) Module fglrx: vendor="FireGL - AMD Technologies Inc."
[    36.374]    compiled for 1.4.99.906, module version = 12.10.5
[    36.374]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    36.375] (II) Loading sub module "fglrxdrm"
[    36.375] (II) LoadModule: "fglrxdrm"
[    36.375] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/linux/libfglrxdrm.so
[    36.406] (II) Module fglrxdrm: vendor="FireGL - AMD Technologies Inc."
[    36.406]    compiled for 1.4.99.906, module version = 12.10.5
[    36.406] (II) AMD Proprietary Linux Driver Version Identifier:12.10.05
[    36.406] (II) AMD Proprietary Linux Driver Release Identifier: 12.104                               
[    36.406] (II) AMD Proprietary Linux Driver Build Date: Mar 28 2013 21:07:25
[    36.406] (++) using VT number 7

[    36.416] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fglrx
[    36.612] (II) Loading PCS database from /etc/ati/amdpcsdb /etc/ati/amdpcsdb.default
[    36.632] ukiDynamicMajor: found major device number 252
[    36.632] ukiDynamicMajor: found major device number 252
[    36.632] ukiOpenByBusid: Searching for BusID PCI:1:0:0
[    36.632] ukiOpenDevice: node name is /dev/ati/card0
[    36.632] ukiOpenDevice: open result is 8, (OK)
[    37.447] ukiOpenByBusid: ukiOpenMinor returns 8
[    37.447] ukiOpenByBusid: ukiGetBusid reports PCI:1:0:0
[    37.540] (--) Chipset Supported AMD Graphics Processor (0x6760) found
[    37.551] (WW) fglrx: No matching Device section for instance (BusID PCI:0@1:0:1) found
[    37.552] (II) AMD Video driver is running on a device belonging to a group targeted for this release
[    37.552] (II) AMD Video driver is signed
[    37.553] (II) fglrx(0): pEnt->device->identifier=0x7fc31790ba10
[    37.553] (II) fglrx(0): === [xdl_xs112_atiddxPreInit] === begin
[    37.553] (II) Loading sub module "vgahw"
[    37.553] (II) LoadModule: "vgahw"
[    37.553] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libvgahw.so
[    37.573] (II) Module vgahw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    37.573]    compiled for 1.12.4, module version = 0.1.0
[    37.573]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 12.1
[    37.573] (**) fglrx(0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
[    37.573] (II) fglrx(0): Pixel depth = 24 bits stored in 4 bytes (32 bpp pixmaps)
[    37.573] (==) fglrx(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[    37.573] (**) fglrx(0): Option "DPMS" "true"
[    37.573] (==) fglrx(0): RGB weight 888
[    37.573] (II) fglrx(0): Using 8 bits per RGB 
[    37.573] (==) fglrx(0): Buffer Tiling is ON
[    37.574] (II) Loading sub module "fglrxdrm"
[    37.574] (II) LoadModule: "fglrxdrm"
[    37.574] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/linux/libfglrxdrm.so
[    37.574] (II) Module fglrxdrm: vendor="FireGL - AMD Technologies Inc."
[    37.574]    compiled for 1.4.99.906, module version = 12.10.5
[    37.578] ukiDynamicMajor: found major device number 252
[    37.578] ukiDynamicMajor: found major device number 252
[    37.578] ukiOpenByBusid: Searching for BusID PCI:1:0:0
[    37.578] ukiOpenDevice: node name is /dev/ati/card0
[    37.578] ukiOpenDevice: open result is 11, (OK)
[    37.578] ukiOpenByBusid: ukiOpenMinor returns 11
[    37.578] ukiOpenByBusid: ukiGetBusid reports PCI:1:0:0
[    37.578] (**) fglrx(0): NoAccel = NO
[    37.578] (**) fglrx(0): AMD 2D Acceleration Architecture enabled
[    37.578] (--) fglrx(0): Chipset: "AMD Radeon HD 6400M Series" (Chipset = 0x6760)
[    37.578] (--) fglrx(0): (PciSubVendor = 0x104d, PciSubDevice = 0x9081)
[    37.578] (==) fglrx(0): board vendor info: third party graphics adapter - NOT original AMD
[    37.578] (--) fglrx(0): Linear framebuffer (phys) at 0xe0000000
[    37.578] (--) fglrx(0): MMIO registers at 0xf7e20000
[    37.579] (--) fglrx(0): I/O port at 0x0000d000
[    37.579] (==) fglrx(0): ROM-BIOS at 0x000c0000
[    37.591] (II) fglrx(0): AC Adapter is used
[    37.620] (II) fglrx(0): Primary V_BIOS segment is: 0xc000
[    37.705] (II) Loading sub module "vbe"
[    37.705] (II) LoadModule: "vbe"
[    37.706] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libvbe.so
[    37.719] (II) Module vbe: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    37.719]    compiled for 1.12.4, module version = 1.1.0
[    37.719]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 12.1
[    37.720] (II) fglrx(0): VESA BIOS detected
[    37.720] (II) fglrx(0): VESA VBE Version 3.0
[    37.720] (II) fglrx(0): VESA VBE Total Mem: 16384 kB
[    37.721] (II) fglrx(0): VESA VBE OEM: AMD ATOMBIOS
[    37.721] (II) fglrx(0): VESA VBE OEM Software Rev: 13.9
[    37.721] (II) fglrx(0): VESA VBE OEM Vendor: (C) 1988-2010, AMD Technologies Inc. 
[    37.721] (II) fglrx(0): VESA VBE OEM Product: SEYMOUR
[    37.721] (II) fglrx(0): VESA VBE OEM Product Rev: 01.00
[    37.721] (II) fglrx(0): AMD Video BIOS revision 9 or later detected
[    37.721] (--) fglrx(0): Video RAM: 524288 kByte, Type: DDR3
[    37.721] (II) fglrx(0): PCIE card detected
[    37.721] (--) fglrx(0): Using per-process page tables (PPPT) as GART.
[    37.721] (WW) fglrx(0): board is an unknown third party board, chipset is supported
[    37.721] (II) fglrx(0): [FB] MC range(MCFBBase = 0xf00000000, MCFBSize = 0x20000000)
[    37.721] (II) fglrx(0): RandR 1.2 support is enabled!
[    37.721] (II) fglrx(0): RandR 1.2 rotation support is enabled!
[    37.721] (==) fglrx(0): Center Mode is disabled 
[    37.721] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[    37.721] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[    37.721] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[    37.735] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    37.735]    compiled for 1.12.4, module version = 1.0.0
[    37.735]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[    37.735] (II) Loading sub module "ddc"
[    37.735] (II) LoadModule: "ddc"
[    37.735] (II) Module "ddc" already built-in
[    37.961] (II) fglrx(0): Output LVDS using monitor section aticonfig-Monitor[0]-0
[    37.961] (II) fglrx(0): Output DFP1 has no monitor section
[    37.961] (II) fglrx(0): Output CRT1 has no monitor section
[    37.961] (II) Loading sub module "ddc"
[    37.961] (II) LoadModule: "ddc"
[    37.961] (II) Module "ddc" already built-in
[    37.961] (II) fglrx(0): Connected Display0: LVDS
[    37.961] (II) fglrx(0):  Display0: Failed to get EDID information. 
[    37.962] (II) fglrx(0): EDID for output LVDS
[    37.962] (II) fglrx(0): Manufacturer: AUO  Model: 223c  Serial#: 0
[    37.962] (II) fglrx(0): Year: 2010  Week: 0
[    37.962] (II) fglrx(0): EDID Version: 1.3
[    37.962] (II) fglrx(0): Digital Display Input
[    37.962] (II) fglrx(0): Max Image Size [cm]: horiz.: 31  vert.: 17
[    37.962] (II) fglrx(0): Gamma: 2.20
[    37.962] (II) fglrx(0): No DPMS capabilities specified
[    37.962] (II) fglrx(0): Supported color encodings: RGB 4:4:4 YCrCb 4:4:4 
[    37.962] (II) fglrx(0): First detailed timing is preferred mode
[    37.962] (II) fglrx(0): redX: 0.590 redY: 0.345   greenX: 0.340 greenY: 0.570
[    37.962] (II) fglrx(0): blueX: 0.150 blueY: 0.120   whiteX: 0.313 whiteY: 0.329
[    37.962] (II) fglrx(0): Manufacturer's mask: 0
[    37.962] (II) fglrx(0): Supported detailed timing:
[    37.962] (II) fglrx(0): clock: 72.0 MHz   Image Size:  309 x 173 mm
[    37.962] (II) fglrx(0): h_active: 1366  h_sync: 1404  h_sync_end 1426 h_blank_end 1466 h_border: 0
[    37.962] (II) fglrx(0): v_active: 768  v_sync: 771  v_sync_end 777 v_blanking: 818 v_border: 0
[    37.962] (II) fglrx(0): Unknown vendor-specific block f
[    37.962] (II) fglrx(0):  AUO
[    37.962] (II) fglrx(0):  B140XW02 V2
[    37.962] (II) fglrx(0): EDID (in hex):
[    37.962] (II) fglrx(0):     00ffffffffffff0006af3c2200000000
[    37.962] (II) fglrx(0):     00140103801f11780a10b59758579226
[    37.962] (II) fglrx(0):     1e505400000001010101010101010101
[    37.962] (II) fglrx(0):     010101010101201c5664500032302616
[    37.962] (II) fglrx(0):     360035ad100000180000000f00000000
[    37.962] (II) fglrx(0):     00000000000000000020000000fe0041
[    37.962] (II) fglrx(0):     554f0a202020202020202020000000fe
[    37.962] (II) fglrx(0):     004231343058573032205632200a00fc
[    37.962] (II) fglrx(0): EDID vendor "AUO", prod id 8764
[    37.962] (II) fglrx(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[    37.962] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1366x768"x0.0   72.00  1366 1404 1426 1466  768 771 777 818 -hsync -vsync (49.1 kHz eP)
[    37.962] (II) fglrx(0): Printing probed modes for output LVDS
[    37.962] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1366x768"x60.0   72.00  1366 1404 1426 1466  768 771 777 818 -hsync -vsync (49.1 kHz)
[    37.962] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1360x768"x60.0   72.00  1360 1404 1426 1466  768 771 777 818 -hsync -vsync (49.1 kHz)
[    37.962] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1280x768"x60.0   72.00  1280 1404 1426 1466  768 771 777 818 -hsync -vsync (49.1 kHz)
[    37.962] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1280x720"x60.0   72.00  1280 1404 1426 1466  720 771 777 818 -hsync -vsync (49.1 kHz)
[    37.962] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1024x768"x60.0   72.00  1024 1404 1426 1466  768 771 777 818 -hsync -vsync (49.1 kHz)
[    37.962] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1024x600"x60.0   72.00  1024 1404 1426 1466  600 771 777 818 -hsync -vsync (49.1 kHz)
[    37.962] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "800x600"x60.0   72.00  800 1404 1426 1466  600 771 777 818 -hsync -vsync (49.1 kHz)
[    37.962] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "800x480"x60.0   72.00  800 1404 1426 1466  480 771 777 818 -hsync -vsync (49.1 kHz)
[    37.962] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "640x480"x60.0   72.00  640 1404 1426 1466  480 771 777 818 -hsync -vsync (49.1 kHz)
[    37.962] (II) fglrx(0): EDID for output DFP1
[    37.962] (II) fglrx(0): EDID for output CRT1
[    37.962] (II) fglrx(0): Output LVDS connected
[    37.962] (II) fglrx(0): Output DFP1 disconnected
[    37.962] (II) fglrx(0): Output CRT1 disconnected
[    37.962] (II) fglrx(0): Using exact sizes for initial modes
[    37.962] (II) fglrx(0): Output LVDS using initial mode 1366x768
[    37.962] (II) fglrx(0): Display dimensions: (310, 170) mm
[    37.962] (II) fglrx(0): DPI set to (111, 114)
[    37.962] (II) fglrx(0): Eyefinity capable adapter detected.
[    37.963] (II) fglrx(0): Adapter AMD Radeon HD 6400M Series has 4 configurable heads and 1 displays connected.
[    37.963] (==) fglrx(0):  PseudoColor visuals disabled
[    37.963] (II) Loading sub module "ramdac"
[    37.963] (II) LoadModule: "ramdac"
[    37.963] (II) Module "ramdac" already built-in
[    37.963] (==) fglrx(0): NoDRI = NO
[    37.963] (==) fglrx(0): Capabilities: 0x00000000
[    37.963] (==) fglrx(0): CapabilitiesEx: 0x00000000
[    37.963] (==) fglrx(0): OpenGL ClientDriverName: "fglrx_dri.so"
[    37.963] (==) fglrx(0): UseFastTLS=0
[    37.963] (II) fglrx(0): Shadow Primary option: ShadowPrimary is enabled
[    37.963] (--) Depth 24 pixmap format is 32 bpp
[    37.963] (II) Loading extension ATIFGLRXDRI
[    37.963] (II) fglrx(0): doing swlDriScreenInit
[    37.963] (II) fglrx(0): swlDriScreenInit for fglrx driver
[    37.963] ukiDynamicMajor: found major device number 252
[    37.963] ukiDynamicMajor: found major device number 252
[    37.963] ukiDynamicMajor: found major device number 252
[    37.963] ukiOpenByBusid: Searching for BusID PCI:1:0:0
[    37.963] ukiOpenDevice: node name is /dev/ati/card0
[    37.963] ukiOpenDevice: open result is 12, (OK)
[    37.963] ukiOpenByBusid: ukiOpenMinor returns 12
[    37.963] ukiOpenByBusid: ukiGetBusid reports PCI:1:0:0
[    37.963] (II) fglrx(0): [uki] DRM interface version 1.0
[    37.963] (II) fglrx(0): [uki] created "fglrx" driver at busid "PCI:1:0:0"
[    37.963] (II) fglrx(0): [uki] added 8192 byte SAREA at 0x2000
[    37.963] (II) fglrx(0): [uki] mapped SAREA 0x2000 to 0x7fc315a0c000
[    37.963] (II) fglrx(0): [uki] framebuffer handle = 0x3000
[    37.963] (II) fglrx(0): [uki] added 1 reserved context for kernel
[    37.963] (II) fglrx(0): swlDriScreenInit done
[    37.963] (II) fglrx(0): Kernel Module Version Information:
[    37.963] (II) fglrx(0):     Name: fglrx
[    37.963] (II) fglrx(0):     Version: 12.10.5
[    37.963] (II) fglrx(0):     Date: Mar 28 2013
[    37.963] (II) fglrx(0):     Desc: AMD FireGL DRM kernel module
[    37.963] (II) fglrx(0): Kernel Module version matches driver.
[    37.963] (II) fglrx(0): Kernel Module Build Time Information:
[    37.963] (II) fglrx(0):     Build-Kernel UTS_RELEASE:        3.2.0-4-amd64
[    37.963] (II) fglrx(0):     Build-Kernel MODVERSIONS:        yes
[    37.963] (II) fglrx(0):     Build-Kernel __SMP__:            yes
[    37.963] (II) fglrx(0):     Build-Kernel PAGE_SIZE:          0x1000
[    37.963] (II) fglrx(0): [uki] register handle = 0x00004000
[    37.987] (II) fglrx(0): DRI initialization successfull
[    38.015] (II) fglrx(0): FBADPhys: 0xf00000000 FBMappedSize: 0x01004000
```